# How to plot multiple figures on the same script PYTHON

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to plot multiple figures in python on the same script. So far I've been successful but they only open one at a time, and I can only see another if I close the prior figure. They are all labelled Figure 1. Any suggestions?

```
#Code to satisfy variables....
plt.scatter(no_dep_x_ps_on_ldpe, no_dep_y_ps_on_ldpe, label='No Deposition', color='black', marker='^')
plt.scatter(dep_x_ps_on_ldpe, dep_y_ps_on_ldpe, label='Deposition', color='grey', marker='s')
plt.title('Deposition Window PS-on-LDPE')
plt.xlabel('Particle Temp [C\u00b0]')
plt.ylabel('Particle Impact Velocity [m/s]')
plt.legend()

plt.show()

plt.scatter(no_dep_x_ps_on_ps, no_dep_y_ps_on_ps, label='No Deposition', color='black', marker='^')
plt.scatter(dep_x_ps_on_ps, dep_y_ps_on_ps, label='Deposition', color='grey', marker='s')
plt.title('Deposition Window PS-on-PS')
plt.xlabel('Particle Temp [C\u00b0]')
plt.ylabel('Particle Impact Velocity [m/s]')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: If I get you correct, a good way is to have two on the same plot? You need to use subplot..  https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

Comment: Do you need all the plots to be on screen at the same time?  have you tried saving them to file?